# Output archive comment of a zip file

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, zip

How can I output the comment archive of a zip file? Basically I want to copy the zip archive comment to the clipboard.

```
zip -z file
```

prompts me to enter a new comment, how can I only output it, without prompt?

Answer (score 10):

You need to use `unzip` and not `zip` to do so.

```
unzip -z file
```

will output the comments saved in the zip file.

Answer (score 0):

In android, busybox unzip has no -z option (assuming busybox is even installed).

`ZIP="/path/to/archive.zip"; X=$(echo . | zip -z "$ZIP" | head -2 | tail -1); echo $X | zip -z "$ZIP" >/dev/null; echo $X`